# How to change text font and size in R View()?

Tags: r, xorg, ess

When I run

```
a <- data.frame(col1 = c(1,2,5,8,2,2), col2=c(34,5,64,54,23,3))
View(a)
```

I get a popup window with my data as I hope, but the font size and face are not good for me.

[image]

I have looked at the documentation for `View()` and `dataentry`. While it suggests I might change foreground or background colours in .Xresources, there is no mention of the font face or size setting.

Is there a way to set font face and size in the View() window?

I don't use Rstudio, instead I run R via Emacs + ESS on Linux. (Ubuntu 18.04.05 (LTS) with i3, X.Org version 1.19.6, with empty .Xresources.)

Comment: Probably you are writing your code in R studio. I think you can edit theme settings in R studio

Comment: I am not using RStudio, rather Emacs and the ESS package as I mentioned at the end. I'll add a line to clarify.